# Maven repo and experimental git branches

Tags: git, maven

I have do my main development on the git `master` branch, and build with `mvn`. Sometimes, I create a temporary "experimental" branch to pursue a particular algorithm idea or refactor. Most of those experiments don't lead where I want them to go, so I blow the branch away again and go back to `master`.

Question: how do I best keep the `~/.m2` repository from being polluted by the code on the experimental branch? Both branches have the same version identifier (there is no point in incrementing on the experimental branch) and so the builds overwrite each other.

I could create different build profiles specifying different `.m2` directories, but I know that I'll forget to specify them occasionally when building. Also, that would require me to create a different profile for each throw-away branch, and that makes throw-away branches far less appealing than they are in git.

Is there a better way?

Update: I'm thinking I could use a different artifact ID on a different branch. Now if there was a mechanism in maven to declare a property like this:

```
<myprop>$(git branch | grep '^\*' | cut -f 2 -d ' ')</myprop>
```

but I guess there isn't.

Comment: Do you have one multi-module project or a bunch of standalone modules?

Comment: I have both and would like to solve both.

Comment: ok I see. The problem is that in case of standalone modules you have to rebuild them because in fact they have independent lifecycles. Different ~/.m2 repositories for each branch is a big pain if your project has a lot of dependencies. Personally I prefer to stick to multi-module projects with shaded jar as an artifact which saves me from any need in `mvn install`. But as far as I understand you have to install artifacts locally to build dependent projects. Am I right?

Comment: You are indeed right!

Comment: Instead of incrementing the version number, you could give it a suffix.